# iphone animation from image set

Tags: ios

Ive got about 5,000 images labeled image_1 through to image_5000 how can I create an animation that will cycle through each image and then repeat?
This is an iPhone application and is just for my personal use, any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I am using, why is it not working.

```
 //.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
int i;
}
@end
```

---

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{

i = 0;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(loop) 
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(void)loop{
if (i<MAX_IMAGES) {

    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d.bmp",i]];
    NSLog(@"Image:%d",i);
        i+=1;
    if (i >= MAX_IMAGES) {
        i = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I feel like I've made a really stupid mistake so don't be too harsh Im only 15

Comment: Should i be reset to 0 rather than 1?

Comment: no the images start at 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a NSTimer to load an image at a time into an UIIMageView. That way you can have controlled of the interval between images changes and minimized memory usage. Let me know if you need sample code.

Comment: I took this approach but I get really weird results.
firstly I have all ready checked the images 10 times and they are all in order. but when I run the app image_3 and image_2 are swapped around. Im only on a small scale of 10 images to test that its working and I and really confused, also i put in a brake point to see what the int was and it was 111594320???

Answer (score 1):

This is too many images to use the automatic version, so you will have to implement it yourself using a [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009031).  In your display link function, you should swap the image of your image view to the next image.  If you don't understand, there are plenty of tutorials about how to use CADisplayLink on the web ;).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of the naive approach. You are likely to run into memory issues, but without  seeing your image set, it's difficult to know whether it will suffice or not.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5000];
for(size_t i = 0; i <= 5000; ++i) {
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d", i]]];
}

imageView.animationImages = images;
imageView.animationDuration = 250.0;
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;

[imageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: I think you mean all those properties minus the "animation" (images, duration, and repeatCount).  The animated image constructor only allows for 1024 images so I don't know if that will be a problem or not either...

Comment: Note that I'm using a `UIImageView` here rather than the animation properties directly on `UIImage`. There may very well be platform limitations with both of them; I've certainly never created an animated `UIImageView` with 500 images, much less 5000.

Comment: whoops, you are correct!  I was looking at UIImage and not UIImageView

Comment: The above code will obviously crash the device when it runs out of memory. Any use of animationImages will when there are more than just a couple of images of decent size.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using Cocos2d. Not sure if it can handle 5000 images though.

5000 images sounds a lot like a movie. Have you thought about approaching it from that angle?